# Fast way to copy a Blog x to another domain/server without deleting it

Tags: migration

Let's say I have a Wordpress blog named **X**, and I want another blog **Y** 
What is the best way to have the exact same copy of **X** on another domain, so I can create my **Y** blog with the same plugins, themes, without having to download them again from the WordPress admin panel.

What I've found is :

- Either copying the whole wp folder and upload it to the other domains
  server.
- Or using some plugins, but I don't really know which one and if it's
  a good practice.

So is there a good practice to copy a Blog **X** to another domain/server without deleting it.It's not really a migration as I don't want to migrate, just copying it **X** and it's themes, plugins on **Y**

Answer (score 0):

You can use backupbuddy plugin. There are other free plugins but I didn't test them.

However... it is also easy clone the website without using a plugin. What you need to do is to zip all site files and downalod database. Then you need to open .sql file with some code editor where you need to change site URL with new one, and you need to do that on every place. Use some code editor - Find and Replace All.

When that is done upload zip file in wanted folder and unzip it. You also need to create new database where you need to import edited .sql file.

Add user and permissions to database.

Final step is to set up wp-config file.

When you are done, browse your new site URL and log into WP-admin. Navigate to Permalinks and click on Save button...

and you are done.